# Given a collection of divs, how can I determine the last one in a row

Tags: jquery, html

Say I have `<div><div><div><div><div><div>` etc, with each div floated and having a fixed width.

How can I programmatically (using jquery or otherwise) determine the which of the divs will be at the end of a row, as rendered in the browser?

In other words, the same page rendered on a large screen:

```
[ ][ ][ ][ ]<-I want this one
[ ][ ][ ]<-and this one
```

and a smaller screen

```
[ ][ ]<-I want this one
[ ][ ]<-and this one
[ ] etc
```

Comment: iterate over them and compare their position?

Comment: whether all `div` are from same row?

Answer (score 2):

This question has intrigued me as having much practical relevance. I like the OP's own answer, but I thought it could be  done  declaratively (and more intuitively),  with a single method chain on the container. So I've cooked it down to this:

```
$("#container div").each(function () { 
    $(this).toggleClass('rightMost',
        $(this).is(':last-child')  || 
        $(this).position().left >= $(this).next().position().left
    );
});
```

Since `.next()` returns null on the last element, you need to have the condition also pass for the last element with `.is(':last-child')`

Also, since the container may be only wide enough for one element -- in which case all should be marked as right-most -- the condition should apply when the current element has position().left that is greater than *or equal to* that of .next().

You can see it working and wrapped in a funciton that gets fired both on document-ready and window-resize here: http://jsfiddle.net/mhfaust/TdXZJ/

**Update** 
The conditions can be applied more generally (though a little less elegantly) if the desired effect is not just applying/removing a class-name, like this:

```
$("#container div").each(function () { 
    if($(this).is(':last-child') || $(this).position().left >= $(this).next().position().left)){
        // do one thing...
    }

    else{
        // ... or do the other.
    }
});
```

Comment: Would this approach still work if you wanted to do something other than adding a class to it?

Comment: @Jack: there is no general `.toggleFunction()` that applies one function or another based on a condition, but you can still use the conditions inside an if block (see update). Note also: there *was* an overload of toggle(), prior to jQuery 1.9, that took 2 functions, but it applied them in an alternating, per-invocation sequence rather than based on a condition.

Comment: @Jack: come to think of it, your solution using a prev var to hold the index is probably a lot more efficient than using `.prev()` call over and over.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

html:

```
<div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div>
<div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div>
<div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div>
```

js:

```
   $(window).resize(function(){
    var mostRight=null;

    $("div").each(function(){
       var $this = $(this);
       if (mostRight==null) mostRight=$this;
         if(mostRight.position().left<$this.position().left){
            mostRight=$this;   
          }      

    });

    var mostRights=[];
    $("div").each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if( $this.position().left==mostRight.position().left){
            mostRights.push($this);
        }
    });
    mostRights.push($("div").last());

    $("div").css("background-color","white");
    for(var i=0;i<mostRights.length;i++){
     $(mostRights[i]).css("background-color","red");
    }



});
```

css:

```
div{

    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:50px;
}
```

look here:

http://jsfiddle.net/bznEx/3/

Answer (score 1):

Based on clph3r's answer I found out that the simplest way to solve this is to run through the array backwards:

```
var prev=-1;
    $($("#container div").get().reverse()).each(function(){
       var $this = $(this)
       if($this.position().left>prev){
           $this.addClass("right");
       }
       prev=$this.position().left;
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bznEx/13/)

Comment: Replace the if block with `$this.toggleClass('right', $this.position().left>prev)`. Not only is that just a bit cleaner, but by toggling each element based on the condition, you can then wrap this in in a function, and call the function both on `$(document).ready()`, and on `window.onresize`, so that the right-most blocks are always correctly marked. I'll be using this! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following piece of jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var k = Math.floor(($('body').width())/$('div').width());
    $('div:nth-child('+k+'n)').each(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color','blue');
    });
});
```

This code computes the index of the last div of a row. Then, it uses `nth-child(equation)` selector, with `equation` set to `k + 'n'`, i.e., selecting all divs that have an index which is a multiple of `k`, i.e., **all divs which are the last of their row**.

Here's a complete example, that paints blue all the (originally red) divs in the last column:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> <head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var k = Math.floor(($('body').width())/$('div').width());
    $('div:nth-child('+k+'n)').each(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color','blue');
    });
});
</script>
<style>
div {
   width: 2em;
   height: 2em;
   background-color: red;
   border-radius: 4px;
   display: inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>

</body> </html>
```

Comment: That's very unlikely since this approach heavily relies on the fact that the div's are of fixed **width**.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `.last()` or the `:last-child` selector.

```
var lastDiv = $("div").last();
```

Or:

```
<div id="container">
   <div><div><div><div><div><div>
</div>

var lastChild = $("#container:last-child");
```

http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/

Comment: I think he wants to determine which element is last in a line before any float drops, not the last child of the container, per se.

Comment: don't think my question was clear enough, I've added a diagram to explain

Answer (score 0):

By using jquery jquery , something like this

```
$("div:last").val();
```